# SQL-Select query to results all 12 months even if data not exist

Tags: sql

I have table names 'employeecount' with following data

```
month , driver, engineer
January , 100,200
March , 300,400
December , 500,600
```

I want the following result

```
January , 100,200
February , 0,0
March , 300,400
April , 0,0
May , 0,0
June , 0,0
July , 0,0
August , 0,0
September , 0,0
October , 0,0
November , 0,0
December , 500,600
```

I have tried creating month reference table and doing left outer join. But it dint work.

Please help to make the query.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2):

Try this sample query with LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT ref.month, emp.driver, emp.engineer 
FROM referencetable  ref
LEFT JOIN  employeecount emp
ON emp.month = ref.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually left join will work as exactly what you expect. Try with this query:

```
select rm.month,e.driver, e.engineer 
from 
refmonth rm left join employeecount e 
on (e.month=rm.month);
```

Here, i put the reference month table as `refmonth` as shown below:

```
month
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

So the query result will contain `NULL` instead of `0` as you mention.